# How to map html files in a sub folder with domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way to redirect to a sub folder inside the `public_html` folder using .htaccess?

My project files and index.html resides `/public_html/myapi`

The domain name https://www.api.example.com it should show the `public_html/myapi` instead of public_html?

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible. If you unconditionally want to rewrite *all* requests then this should get you started:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /myapi/$1 [END]
```

This assumes two things:

1. that `/public_html` actually is the folder in the server side file system that the http server `DOCUMENT_ROOT` setting points to and
2. that you do *not* actually want a "redirect" as stated in the question, but an "internal rewriting", so that the URL shown in the browser's URL bar stays unchanged.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you. But I have only able to access the cPanel

Comment: When I use your code, it shows the directory listing. So I append `Options All -Indexes`. Then I receive `Error 403`

Comment: Well, 403 means forbidden, that has nothing to do with these rewriting rules. If your URL  targets a folder after the rewriting and you disabled a directory listing, then what do you expect to receive AS a response?

Comment: Then, How can I disable the directory listing too?

Comment: It apparently already IS disabled... Apart from that: why don't you simply take a look into the documentation?